# pass bash variable to filename for grep command

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I have a file that contains a list of filename prefixes that I want to perform grep on to grep out a specific set of lines that contain coordinates for a subsequent calculation of root-mean squared deviation that I will carry out with a one-liner in awk. I've verified that the syntax for my regular expression will work on a single file, but when I go to utilize the bash variable from my for loop, grep will not recognize the variable. I've tried multiple permutations of double quotes, escape characters, and squiggly braces, but none of them produce the desired output. Here is what the raw data looks like after initial grep and pipe to 2nd grep execution to clean up the data for the awk step:

```
grep " [A-Z] " ../glide-dock_SP_8CHM/ligands/3579831839.sdf | grep " 'F\|S\|C\|O\|N "
    2.7118    4.0281   21.0125 S   0  0  0  0  0  0
    4.0921    3.8708   21.4967 O   0  0  0  0  0  0
    1.8208    2.8602   20.9648 O   0  0  0  0  0  0
    1.9954    5.2598   21.8979 N   0  0  1  0  0  0
    2.8079    4.6789   19.3978 N   0  0  0  0  0  0
    2.3264    6.6613   21.7269 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
    0.5679    5.5328   21.8880 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
    3.8805    4.1396   18.5518 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
    1.5591    4.8798   18.6409 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
    0.9197    6.9883   22.3042 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
    0.8840    7.1094   23.8539 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
    0.1007    8.1332   21.6760 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
   -0.1257    6.7465   24.4613 O   0  0  0  0  0  0
    1.9559    7.6325   24.4759 N   0  0  0  0  0  0
    0.9264    9.3760   21.3740 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
    2.1242    7.8085   25.9208 C   0  0  1  0  0  0
    1.5512    9.5358   20.1194 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
    1.0887   10.3742   22.3570 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
    3.4722    7.2469   26.3919 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
    1.7964    9.2425   26.3963 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
    2.3648   10.6567   19.8673 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
    1.8942   11.5002   22.1018 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
    3.4888    6.2142   27.0561 O   0  0  0  0  0  0
    4.6188    7.8580   26.0568 N   0  0  0  0  0  0
    2.6369   10.3760   25.7768 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
    2.5397   11.6366   20.8599 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
    4.8138    9.1019   25.3276 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
    4.1501   10.2988   26.0247 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
```

I have a file list that contains the prefixes for all of my files that I wish to perform this search and extract for, so I thought that a for statement would be the way to go. Here was my initial attempt:

```
for i in $(cat ligand-list.txt)
> do
> grep " [A-Z] " ../glide-dock_SP_8CHM/ligands/$i.sdf | grep " 'F\|S\|C\|O\|N " | awk '{print $1,$2,$3}' > $i_8CHM.xyz
> done
grep: ../glide-dock_SP_8CHM/ligands/ligand-list.txt.sdf: No such file or directory
```

I know that I needed some sort of character escape around my variable in the grep command, so I thought to use double-quotes, but that produced the same output as above. Adding the escape character with the double quotes treats $i as a literal string:

```
for i in $(cat ligand-list.txt)
> do
> grep " [A-Z] " ../glide-dock_SP_8CHM/ligands/"\$i".sdf | grep " 'F\|S\|C\|O\|N " | awk '{print $1,$2,$3}' > $i_8CHM.xyz
> done
.
.
.
grep: ../glide-dock_SP_8CHM/ligands/$i.sdf: No such file or directory
```

Adding squiggly braces was the closest I've been able to get, as my for variable is passed as a string to grep, but grep is now treating the escape character and squiggly braces as a string within the bash variable:

```
for i in $(cat ligand-list.txt)
> do
> grep " [A-Z] " ../glide-dock_SP_8CHM/ligands/"\{$i}".sdf | grep " 'F\|S\|C\|O\|N " | awk '{print $1,$2,$3}' > $i_8CHM.xyz
> done
.
.
.
grep: ../glide-dock_SP_8CHM/ligands/\{3579831839}.sdf: No such file or directory
```

Any other combination or change in position of ,",{} produces the same results. From my reading of SO and grep documentation, I thought that all I needed was double-quotes to have my bash variable passed as a literal string, but I think that is just for the regex that grep searches for and not the file that grep is searching. Would really appreciate some clarification on this, as I've been banging my head on the keyboard with this for most of the day.

Comment: Just `"$i"` suffices. If that doesn't work you're doing something else wrong (and `for i in $(cat anything)` **is** wrong, so there are in fact other problems here).

Comment: See [DontReadLinesWithFor](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) for some context.

Comment: ...anyhow -- where I'd suggest you go next is to use xtrace logging to compare the commands you get when just using `"$i"` with what those commands need to be to work correctly. `bash -x yourscript`, or put `set -x` in the script where you want it to start tracing and `set +x` where you want it to disable tracing.

Comment: Also, silly question, but _does_ `../glide-dock_SP_8CHM/ligands/ligand-list.txt.sdf` exist? Since `..` is a relative rather than absolute path, whether it works depends on your current working directory, which is _not_ necessarily the same as the directory you saved your script in; think about explicitly logging the value of `"$PWD"/../glide-dock_SP_8CHM/ligands/"$i".sdf`, and make sure the lookup isn't starting from somewhere other than the location you expect.

Comment: Anyhow -- if you can build a [mre] we could see the problem ourselves and write a definitive answer; but right now nobody but you has your actual input files, your actual directory structure, knowledge of the working directory your script is run in, and all the other details necessary to reproduce this issue.

Comment: (one last resource pointer: for a best-practices way to read a file line-by-line, see [BashFAQ #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001))

Comment: (BTW, what's with the `'` inside `grep " 'F\|S\|C\|O\|N "`? Your regex is matching the `F` only if there's a `'` before it; that doesn't make sense -- and it's only checking for a preceding space before `F` and ` trailing space after `N`, and not requiring such whitespace for any of `S`, `C`, or `O`. I would write the expression that I understand you to be intending as`grep -E '[[:space:]][FSCON][[:space:]]'`)

Comment: (...also, don't use `[A-Z]` -- it's locale-specific; in some language configurations your collation order is like `AaBbCcDd...Zz`, so `A-Z` includes `a`, `b`, `c`... all the way to `y` but not `z`; instead, use `[[:upper:]]` and you match only upper-case characters regardless)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks for the quick response and critique of what I provided. Will try to address your questions as best I can.
- I can modify the code as suggested, but most of the suggestions are clean-up.
- the initial for statement: I was under the impression that `for i in $(cat ligand-list.txt)` was a more appropriate call than `for i in `cat ligand-list.txt``. Either way, they produce the same output:
`for i in $(cat ligand-list.txt)
do
echo $i
done
.
.
.
3577777489
3577794762
3579449366
3579831839
`
So that aspect of the for loop is working correctly.

Comment: Yes, `for i in $(cat ...)` is better than backticks, _but they're both bad_; it's "better" in the sense that poison ivy is better than battery acid -- it's an accurate comparison, but you don't want to get either one on you. Read the linked references. The best-practice way to read a file line-by-line is something more like `while IFS= read -r line; do ...; done <ligand-list.txt` (or if you need to use stdin within the loop, perhaps `while IFS= read -r line <&3; do ...; done 3<ligand-list.txt` -- BashFAQ #1 goes into this).

Comment: - I've executed this for loop in the relative path and also switched to the path where my files are located in. When you ask "does ../glide-dock_SP_8CHM/ligands/ligand-list.txt.sdf exist?" it does not. What it should be looking for (to take the last line from ligand-list.txt) is glide-dock_SP_8CHM/ligands/3579831839.sdf, with the prefix of the sdf file being the content of variable i defined in the for loop.

Comment: We can't see the contents of your file, so problems happening at that layer are invisible to us. This is part of why we ask for a [mre] -- the shortest possible code complete enough to cause the problem on its own, creating any necessary files/directories/etc.

Comment: I can imagine reasons why what you're writing could cause the bug you describe, though. Let's say your file contains a whitespace-surrounded `*` somewhere -- it gets expanded into a list of files in your current directory, and that injects `ligand-list.txt`. And because _I can't see your screen and your file content_, I can't rule that kind of thing out; that's why it's so frustrating to be given a deeply incomplete picture as you're doing here.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy give me a sec to look over the BashFAQ reference you sent me so I can rework this with a while loop instead of a for statement. I've been using for loops for a long time so need to switch my way of thinking here.

Comment: If you could set up a sandbox in https://repl.it/ or similar that produces the problem (suggesting that one in particular because unlike https://ideone.com/ it provides a writable filesystem), that would be an ideal way to ensure that you're including all the details necessary to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Another way to read a file's contents into an array and loop over it without all the side effects associated with unquoted expansion is `readarray -t varname <filename`, after which you can do `for item in "${varname[@]}"; do ...` -- note that that requires bash 4.0 or later (which should be fine in most places, but isn't default on MacOS since Apple isn't willing to comply with GPLv3 licensing)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy you were absolutely correct that I should have provided a minimal working example -- would have allowed me to find the issue in my source file ligand-list.txt. Thank you for helping me realize this.

Comment: @blakem from one of your other comments it sounds like the issue was an entry in `ligand-test.txt` that did not have a matching file? one (obvious) fix would be to add a conditional as the first step in the `while` loop, eg, `[[ ! -f "../glide-dock_SP_8CHM/ligands/$i.sdf" ]] && echo "no such file : $i" && continue`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setup:

```
$ mkdir -p ../glide-dock_SP_8CHM/ligands

$ cat ligand-list.txt
12345
78900
ABCDE

$ head ../glide-dock_SP_8CHM/ligands/*sdf
==> ../glide-dock_SP_8CHM/ligands/12345.sdf <==
   99.9999   99.9999   12345 A   0  0  0  0  0  0
    2.7118    4.0281   12345 F   0  0  0  0  0  0
   99.9999   99.9999   12345 G   0  0  0  0  0  0
    4.0921    3.8708   12345 S   0  0  0  0  0  0

==> ../glide-dock_SP_8CHM/ligands/78900.sdf <==
   99.9999   99.9999   78900 B   0  0  0  0  0  0
    2.7118    4.0281   78900 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
   99.9999   99.9999   78900 M   0  0  0  0  0  0
    4.0921    3.8708   78900 O   0  0  0  0  0  0

==> ../glide-dock_SP_8CHM/ligands/ABCDE.sdf <==
   99.9999   99.9999   ABCDE L   0  0  0  0  0  0
    2.7118    4.0281   ABCDE O   0  0  0  0  0  0
   99.9999   99.9999   ABCDE Z   0  0  0  0  0  0
    4.0921    3.8708   ABCDE F   0  0  0  0  0  0
```

**NOTES:**

- for rows we're not interested in the 1st/2nd columns are always 99.9999
- for rows of interest 3rd column changed to name of file (easier to eyeball the results)

Modifying OP's `bash / while` code:

```
while read -r i
do
    grep '[[:upper:]]' ../glide-dock_SP_8CHM/ligands/"$i".sdf | grep " [FSCON] " | awk '{print $1,$2,$3}' > "$i"_8CHM.xyz
done < ligand-list.txt
```

Consolidating the 2x `grep` calls:

```
while read -r i
do
    grep " [FSCON] " ../glide-dock_SP_8CHM/ligands/"$i".sdf | awk '{print $1,$2,$3}' > "$i"_8CHM.xyz
done < ligand-list.txt
```

Removing the `grep` call:

```
while read -r i
do
    awk '$4 ~ /^[FSCON]$/ {print $1,$2,$3}' ../glide-dock_SP_8CHM/ligands/"$i".sdf > "$i"_8CHM.xyz
done < ligand-list.txt
```

Use a `while` loop to build a list of files and then a single `awk` script to process said list of files:

```
file_list=()

while read -r line
do
    file_list+=("../glide-dock_SP_8CHM/ligands/${line}.sdf")
done < ligand-list.txt

awk '
FNR==1          { close(outf)                       # close previous output file
                  n = split(FILENAME,a,/[/.]/)      # split current FILENAME on dual characters "/" and "."
                  outf = a[n-1] "_8CHM.xyz"         # create output filename from (n-1)st entry from array a[]
                 }
$4 ~ /^[FSCON]$/ { print $1, $2, $3 > outf }        # print desired columns to output file
' "${file_list[@]}"
```

**NOTES:**

- all of these solutions assume a file exists for each entry in `ligand-list.txt` otherwise we'll generate `'No such file or directory'` errors
- if it's possible a file does not exist then each solution could be updated to include a test to verify the file existence before attempting to process said file

These all generate:

```
$ head *_8CHM.xyz
==> 12345_8CHM.xyz <==
2.7118 4.0281 12345
4.0921 3.8708 12345

==> 78900_8CHM.xyz <==
2.7118 4.0281 78900
4.0921 3.8708 78900

==> ABCDE_8CHM.xyz <==
2.7118 4.0281 ABCDE
4.0921 3.8708 ABCDE
```

Comment: As an alternative to `file_list=( $(awk '{print "../glide-dock_SP_8CHM/ligands/"$0".sdf"}' ligand-list.txt) )` that avoids the unquoted expansion -- think about `readarray -t ligand_list <ligand-list.txt; file_list=( "${ligand_list[@]/#/'../glide-dock_SP_8CHM/ligands/'}" ); file_list=( "${file_list[@]/%/.sdf}" )`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy the initial attempts at file list construction worked as long as no embedded spaces; came up with a similar `readarray/mapfile` approach but was a bit unwieldly so opted for the simpler `while/read/array+=()` approach

Comment: @markp-fuso thanks for the detailed workthrough and reverse engineering my minimal working example. You are correct each of these approaches work and I am grateful to be able to use these to move forward on my project.

What I failed to do was look through line-by-line in my ligand-list.txt and find that there was an additional line that had made it into my file: "ligand-list.txt". So my output error from grep was exactly what it was saying I was getting.